# Unblocking Android device from GCM

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

My company currently have an application with a number of Android devices attached via GCM.

Recently, however, we have discovered that a handful of these devices have a Registered ID token of "BLACKLISTED".

I did some research on this issue and found that this issue could be caused during timeouts between Android device and GCM by not following the exponential back-off approach.

So, implementing the exponential back-off functionality during time-out is one part of the fix.

I was just wondering for the other part of the problem: Is their anyway to unblock these Android devices from GCM or will it automatically unblock after a set amount of time?

Also, do anyone know if this blocking of Android devices happen per IMEI or IP address?

Thanks

Comment: 1. Do these devices include Google Mobile Services  https://source.android.com/compatibility/index.html#licensing-gms
2. Please check that these the devices are NOT clones of a shared fully-initialized-system-image

Comment: We are not making use of any custom Android devices. We use devices like Samsung tablets and just install our particular application on it that uses Google Cloud messaging

Comment: I suggest to factory reset those devices. If the problem persists or it's quite widespread, please contact firebase support.